# Jquery toggle. A similar example

Tags: jquery

Is there a ready-made options such functionality: [Work example](http://www.stoloto.ru/winners?lang=en)

Problem mainly in the correct positioning of the panel.

Or how to do this using query?

Maybe who knows ready examples?
Unfortunately I'm not good in javascript :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery comes with a `slideToggle()` function. For example,

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.panel').slideToggle()
}
```

The `.panel` is the element which is shown when you click the button.
http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle